# How to create dynamic PlotLegends?

Tags: plotting, dynamic

How to add dynamic `PlotLegends` to the below code?

```
DynamicModule[{inputData = 0, dataSet = {}}, 
 Column[{
   InputField[Dynamic[inputData]], 
   Button["Plot", 
    AppendTo[dataSet, Table[inputData + i^j, {i, 5}, {j, 2}]]], 
   Spacer[5],
   Dynamic@ListPlot[dataSet, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> {300}]
   }]]
```

I would like to have a `PlotLegends` which appears only when the `Button` is pressed and `ListPlot` prints the curve, otherwise it shouldn't be visible. Also every time the `Button` is pressed `ListPlot` appends the new curve to the old one, therefore the `PlotLegends` should print the name for every printed curve, but one at the time. How to achieve that?

I spent hours on searching some guidance which could give me at least an idea of how to start, but all I found is for the static `PlotLegends`. This is why I'm asking you for a help.

Cross-posted on [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1635563?p_p_auth=IJFO3dGa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DynamicModule[{inputData = 0, dataSet = {}, lbl = {}}, 
 Column@{InputField[Dynamic[inputData]], 
  Button["Plot", 
   AppendTo[dataSet, Table[inputData + i^j, {i, 5}, {j, 2}]]; 
   AppendTo[lbl, inputData]  (*Creating labels for the Legend*)
  ],  
  Spacer[5],
  Dynamic@ListPlot[dataSet, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> {300}, 
    If[dataSet != {}, PlotLegends -> lbl[[1 ;; Length@dataSet]], Joined -> True]]}]
```

I've repeated the `Joined->True`in the last line to fill the slot for an initial case when there is not curves yet. You can use other ways..
[image]

Comment: It works great! Thank you